# Change materialization name(-prefix) of seed data in the warehouse

Tags: dbt

Currently the seed are automaticaly generated in the warehouse with the name dbt_{schema_name}_seed_data, with {schema_name} being the schema name specified in the profiles.yml.

I want to specify a different name, e.g. dbt_processing_seed_data, without changing the schema name in profile.yml to 'processing'.

Reason behind all this, different devs want to have their own schema so they don't interfere with each other. But it is unnecessary that the (same) seed data is stored multiple times in the warehouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the schema for a seed in your `dbt_project.yml` file. See the [docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/seed-configs).

To get the behavior you describe, where the target name is not prepended to the schema, you need to override the `generate_schema_name` macro by creating a new macro with that name in your project. [Docs on that are here](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/using-custom-schemas#changing-the-way-dbt-generates-a-schema-name). You can use the node's resource type so that this behavior is only applied to seeds.

```
{% macro generate_schema_name(custom_schema_name, node) -%}
    {%- set default_schema = target.schema -%}
    {%- if custom_schema_name is none -%}{{ default_schema }}
    {%- elif node.resource_type == "seed" -%}{{ custom_schema_name | trim }}
    {%- else -%}{{ default_schema }}_{{ custom_schema_name | trim }}
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endmacro %}
```

I'd caution against this, though. Seeds are version-controlled, and really aren't intended to be used for large raw datasets (see the [docs again](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/seeds#faqs)). Since they get checked in alongside code, they should really share the same separation of environments that the code has.

Comment: The first part doesn't really answer my question.
Currenty the used schema name is inserted into the dbt_{schema_name}_seed_data path automatically.

I want to use a different {schema_name} for the seed path (and not the schema_name definied in profiles.yml)

E.g. 2 user have their own schema and two different outputs when they use dbt run:
-dbt_max
-dbt_jim.

But they want to use the same seed data (there shouldnt be two seeds in the warehouse):
-dbt_general_seed_data

and NOT:
-dbt_max_seed_data
-dbt_jim_seed_data.

Comment: @BlueLighthouse I've edited my answer to include more information on how you can override the default schema name generation

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked.

Regarding you second advice, our csv files aren't large.